# Why is my function running but not giving any output?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, args, keyword-argument

```
def func(*args,**kwargs):
    if 'fruit' in args and 'food' in kwargs:
        print('I would like to eat {} {}'.format(args['fruit'], kwargs['food']))

func(fruit='apple',fruit1='banana',food='biryani',dinner='meat')
```

Comment: You should check what the values of args and kwargs are.

Comment: The problem is, now everything is in `kwargs`. Did you mean: `if 'fruit' in kwargs and 'food' in kwargs:`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. If this is homework, read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

*args is used to pass to pass a non-key worded argument list. Try this -

```
def func(*args,**kwargs):
    if len(args)>0 and 'food' in kwargs:
        print('I would like to eat {} {}'.format(args[0], kwargs['food']))

func('apple',fruit1='banana',food='biryani',dinner='meat')
```

check out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs) for more details on *args and **kwargs.